# Optimizando Codigo Jquery

Tags: jquery, optimización

Tengo un código que cree para detectar si una pagina contiene un elemento 'table' y si es así agregar unos elementos a esas tablas como un mensaje si no hay tabla y un mensaje distinto con un link si es que si existe. Ademas de agregar una `div` usando el método `wrap()` para optimizar la tabla para celulares.

Todo me funciona bien pero me gustaría ver como optimizarlo por que siento que hay varias cosas que se repiten por ejemplo `if (table_exist)` se repite 3 veces. Este es el código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var table_exist = ($('table').length); 
var elTitulo = $(".entry-title");

$("table").before("<div id='tablesp'></div>");

if (table_exist) {

  if($('table tbody tr').length < 4){
    // Si hay mesa con menos de 4 lineas 
    elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver BREVE Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
  } else {
    elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
  }

} else {
    elTitulo.after("<p class='speclink'>(No hay tabla especial de especificaciones. Breve descripciÃ³n disponible)</p> ");
}

  //Enlace bajo la tabla para regresar a header

if (table_exist) 
  {
  $('table').after("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink2'>Regresar arriba</a> ");
  } else {
    $('.single #main-content').append("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink3'>Regresar arriba</a>  ");
}


//Agregar div a tables para optimizar en  mobiles
if (table_exist) 
  {
  $('table').wrap("<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>");

  } 
});
```

Comment: El if pregunta lo mismo siempre?, que debe retornar en cada if?

Comment: Pedro Miguel, solo debe retornar un `true` o `false` y basado en esa condicion se toma una accion. Lo que no se como hacer es como preguntar `if (table_exist)` una sola vez y agregar todas las otras condiciones con una sola iteracion de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un buen punto de partida sería agrupar los if, teniendo en cuenta que todos evalúan la misma condición y no son excluyentes, también mejoraría la inclusión del texto en la función after, para no repetir código similar.

Para evitar recorrer el DOM cada vez que usamos un selector en jQuery, es mejor almacenar dichos objetos en variables.

```
$(function() {
  var tablas = $('table'); 
  var elTitulo = $(".entry-title");
  tablas.before("<div id='tablesp'></div>");

  if (tablas.length) {
    var breve_text = '';
    if($('table tbody tr').length < 4) {          
      breve_text = ' BREVE';
    }

    elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver " + breve_text + "Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
    tablas.after("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink2'>Regresar arriba</a> ").wrap("<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>");
  } else {
    elTitulo.after("<p class='speclink'>(No hay tabla especial de especificaciones. Breve descripciÃ³n disponible)</p> ");
    $('.single #main-content').append("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink3'>Regresar arriba</a>  ");
  }
});
```

Comment: Pensaba en un switch, pero esta bien esta respuesta

Comment: Se ve mas elegante, es mas conciso y funciona!

Comment: Hice una edición mejorando el uso de las variables.

Comment: Gracias Shaz pero creo que hay un error  en la parte de `' + breve_text + '` por que me aparece tal cual. Tal vez no lleva las comillas? Ya lo cambie para verlo pero el cache del servidor se tarda un poco en refrescar para poder ver si asi funciona

Comment: Ya lo corregí, era un error de comillas (Estaba usando las simples en vez de dobles).

Comment: Shaz, ya quedo todo bien y funciona tal como se espera pero ahora me surge una duda con el punto de las comillas. El codigo como tal en ese punto especificamente quedo asi:  `elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver " + breve_text + "Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");`  pero como es que puede funcionar si tecnicamente empieza con `("<` y al usar las comillas dobles en `r " + b` no deberia causar eso un conflicto de uso de comillas simples con comillas dobles?

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo dejaría así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("table").before("<div id='tablesp'></div>");

  if ($('table').length) {

    if($('table tbody tr').length < 4) {          
      var breve_text = ' BREVE';
    }

    $(".entry-title").after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver ' + breve_text + 'Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
    $('table').after("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink2'>Regresar arriba</a> ").wrap("<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>");

  } else {  

    $(".entry-title").after("<p class='speclink'>(No hay tabla especial de especificaciones. Breve descripciÃ³n disponible)</p> ");
    $('.single #main-content').append("<a href='#left-area' class='speclink3'>Regresar arriba</a>  ");

  }
});
```

Comment: Tienes razon, despues de eliminar la repeticion del if se vuelve inecesaria la variable.